# how to read and write one specific line in json file python

Tags: python, json

the json file looks like this:

```
{
    "Me": {
        "Age": 0,
        "Location": 0,
        "Friends": 0,
        "Family": 0
    },
    "You": {
        "Age": 0,
        "Location": 0,
        "Friends": 0,
        "Family": 0
    }
}
```

To read ["Me"]["Age"] and assign it to a variable I can use:

```
f = open('info.json')
data = json.load(f)
ageinfo = data["Me"]["Age"]
```

now, if the variable `ageinfo` updates, I want to send it back to the json file and save it. Im not exactly sure how to achieve this, maybe using json.dump? If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you write all the data back to the file using [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Comment: how do I do this with the variables I assign though?

Comment: depends if you take `me_info` = `data["Me"]` changes to `me_info` will be reflected in `data` as dicts are passed by reference. If you take a leaf value like `data["Me"]["Age"]` changes won't show up in the original `data` dict

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use the json.dump function to do that. Imagine you change the content of your dict

```
ageinfo = "new_value"

data["Me"]["Age"] = ageinfo
```

If you want to write it in a file info.json for instance the code would look like this:

```
with open('info.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(data, outfile)
```

This will update the file info.json with the content of your dict (or create it if it does not exist)

Comment: so if I had multiple variables like `data["Me"]["Age"] = ageinfo` and `data["Me"]["Family"] = 10` would it write both with json.dump(data, outfile)?

Comment: Yes it will. It writes the whole dict as a json

Comment: got it working, but when my json file updates it gets rewritten as one long line instead of nicely formatted. Do you know why that is? or how to fix it?

Comment: @pythonmainlol, JSON isn't always the easiest for human readability/manipulation.  Look at the dump function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) and try setting the *indent* option.